# How do I get the Bitmap of the photo taken by calling Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)?

Tags: android

first I created the unique file path to store photo using date:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( 
  Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),"raspberry");
String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy_HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
filePath=new File(file,"SideBySide4_"+dateString+".jpg");
```

I generated a uri from `filePath` using FileProvider I have defined in the manifest and xml:

```
mUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
            filePath);
mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + filePath.getAbsolutePath();//for getting Bitmap in onActivityResult()
```

Then, I launched the camera Intent and give it the Uri to store the photo taken:

```
Intent takePictureIntent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUri);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
```

Then in `onActivityResult()`, I try to get the Bitmap:

```
Uri imageUri=Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            File file=new File(imageUri.getPath());
            try{
                InputStream ims=new FileInputStream(file);
                photoBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                return;
            }
```

**But photoBitmap is null**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can do something like this:

In your onActivityResult(), After clicking a pic, you get the data in `data` So:

```
Bitmap picture = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

Can be used.

Hope it's useful.